Google Sheets Conditional Formatting w/ Multiple Criteria
I'm trying to format a spreadsheet containing timesheet data to flag certain conditions.
Each row of data represents a single pair of clock-in and clock-out times for an employee.
There can be several rows for a single employee representing each time they switched jobs, took a break, etc.
The columns are as follows:



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




First Name
Last Name
Date
Day
Start Time
End Time
Hours
Job
Notes



I need a conditional formatting rule to highlight any row that does not have the word 'Done' in Column I Notes if the following conditions are also met:

Column H Job contains the word 'shop' or 'warehouse' anywhere in the cell contents.
There is at least one other row that has matching values for all of the following columns:

  Column A   First Name
  Column B   Last Name
  Column C   Date
  Column H   Job



I started with the following formula for the same First Name, Last Name and Job, but I can't figure out how to build on it for the text matches in Job and Notes:
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($A$2:$A$983& $B$2:$B$983& $C$2:$C$983& $H$2:$H$983), $A2&$B2& $C2& $H2)>1


Conditional Format Custom Formula
=NOT(REGEXMATCH($I2, "(?i)done")) * 
 REGEXMATCH(""& $H2, "(?i)shop|warehouse") *
 COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2, $B$2:$B, $B2, $C$2:$C,$C2,$H$2:$H,$H2)>1

COUNTIFS  NOT  REGEXMATCH
Variation 1
If Column I Notes will only contain 'Done' by itself the first REGEXMATCH can be dropped:
=($I2 <> "done") * 
 REGEXMATCH(""& $H2, "(?i)shop|warehouse") *
 COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2, $B$2:$B, $B2, $C$2:$C,$C2,$H$2:$H,$H2)>1

Variation 2
If you are confident the text strings targeted by the REGEXMATCH functions are always capitalized properly then (?i) can be omitted from the regular expressions:
=NOT(REGEXMATCH($I2, "Done")) * 
 REGEXMATCH(""& $H2, "Shop|Warehouse") *
 COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2, $B$2:$B, $B2, $C$2:$C,$C2,$H$2:$H,$H2)>1

    or, if based on Variation 1:
=($I2 <> "done") * 
 REGEXMATCH(""& $H2, "Shop|Warehouse") *
 COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2, $B$2:$B, $B2, $C$2:$C,$C2,$H$2:$H,$H2)>1


Done! Thank you!! I posted a new question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/176534/336679
