Google Sheets Conditional Formatting w/ Several Criteria
I posted a similar question here yesterday, but didn't realize that I should have included more info/conditions.
Basically I am starting with a spreadsheet of timesheet data. Each row is a single clock in & clock out duration for an employee. An employee may have just one row per day, or they may have several depending on if they took breaks or switched jobs. Each job is required to have "done" somewhere in column I for each day, but not every row is required to. For example, if someone clocked in & out for job code "warehouse" two different times in one day, only one of those line items is required to have "done" in the notes.
The columns are as follows:



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




First Name
Last Name
Date
Day
Start Time
End Time
Hours
Job
Notes



My goal is for the sheet to flag the rows only when every entry for the same job code on the same day for the same person is missing "done" in notes (this could be 1 row or 3-4 rows) and when the following conditions are also met:
1.) Column H "Job" contains the text "Shop" or "Warehouse" anywhere in the cell contents.
2.) If there are multiple entries that match, but 1 row contains "done" in Column I, then it should not be included in the rule / it should not be highlighted.
Two or more rows are considered matching when the following are the same:
1.) Column A   First Name
2.) Column B   Last Name
3.) Column C   Date
4.) Column H   Job
To summarize, an employee's entry for a particular job on one date should have "done" on any 1 of the rows, whether that is 1 single row or 6 rows.
I started with this formula to find matching rows:
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula($A$2:$A$983&$B$2:$B$983&$C$2:$C$983&$H$2:$H$983),$A2&$B2&$C2&$H2)>1
And then this is the formula suggested to me in my previous question:
=NOT(REGEXMATCH($I2, "(?i)done")) *
REGEXMATCH(""& $H2, "(?i)warehouse") *
COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2, $B$2:$B, $B2, $C$2:$C,$C2,$H$2:$H,$H2)>1
This works to flag only rows that have matches, not necessarily to search all cells in Column I of matching rows to determine if the entire matching dataset meets the conditions, or if single rows with no matches also meet the conditions.
Please feel free to ask clarifying questions, as I feel like I'm having trouble explaining myself clearly. Thank you!

=REGEXMATCH($H2, "(?i)shop|warehouse")*
 NOT(REGEXMATCH($I2, "(?i)done"))*     
 LET(arr,INDEX($A$2:$A& $B$2:$B& $C$2:$C& $H$2:$H),
   cnt,INDEX(arr=INDEX(arr, ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1)),
   SUMPRODUCT(cnt)=SUMPRODUCT(cnt,
     NOT(REGEXMATCH(""&$I$2:$I, "(?i)done"))))


The first two tests (outside of LET) check that the current row isn't marked "done" and that the job is valid. If either of those tests fail then there is no need to continue.
arr stores an array made by combining Columns A to C and H.
cnt stores an array of boolean values based on whether each row in arr matches the current row.
Finally the SUMPRODUCT of cnt is compared to cnt where I is not marked done to ensure they match.

